# Difficulty using SELECT statement in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to set command buttons to enter data into a table. If the record already exists I want the button to update it, and if it does not the button needs to create it. Here's a sample of what the table looks like

```
ID    scenarioID    reductionID    Impact Variable    Variable Impact
1         1              1          Safety             4
2         1              1          Environmental      2
3         1              1          Financial          1
```

In order to accurately locate records, it needs to search for the specific impact variable paired with the scenarioID. I'm trying to use a select statement, but `DoCmd.RunSQL` doesn't work for select statements, and I'm not sure how else to do it.

Here's the code. I left `DoCmd.SQL` in front of the select statement for lack of anything else to place there for now.

```vb
Private Sub Var1R1_Click() 'Stores appropriate values in tImpact upon click

'Declaring database and setting recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tImpact")


'Declaring Variable as Scenario Choice combobox value
Dim Sc As Integer

Sc = Schoice.Value


'Stores impact variable 
Dim impvar1 As String


'Desired impact variable for column 1
impvar1 = DLookup("impactVariable", "tImpactVars", "ID = 1")



DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * FROM tImpact WHERE [Impact Variable] = " & impvar1 & " AND scenarioID = " & Sc



If rs.EOF Then

    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tImpact(scenarioID, [Impact Variable], [Variable Impact])" & "VALUES (" & Sc & ", " & impvar1 & ", 1)"

    MsgBox "Record Added", vbOKOnly


Else

    db.Execute "UPDATE tImpact SET [Variable Impact] = 1 WHERE [Impact Variable] = " & impvar1 & " AND scenarioID = " & Sc

    MsgBox "Record Updated", vbOKOnly


End If

End Sub
```

If anyone can tell me how to get that `SELECT` statement to run, or another way of doing this, that would be great.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Simple syntax error - using a string means enclose with quotes or double quotes. `""" & impvar1 & """`

Comment: Open the recordset don't run SQL . Run is only for an action query. You need `Set rs2  = currentdb.openrecordset "SELECT * FROM tImpact WHERE [Impact Variable] = " & impvar1 & " AND scenarioID = " & Sc`

Comment: @dbmitch what should I replace `DoCmd.RunSQL` with? using it still gives the "must contain an SQL statement" error with that change

@Minty I got a compile error "Expected: end of statement". I tried moving around/adding quotes in case that was the issue but It kept returning the same error.

I also tried using both of your recommendations together `Set rs = . . . """ & impvar1 & """ . . . ` and it still wasn't working

Comment: Good point @Minty

Comment: @Roland - you have the same issues with your UPDATE and INSERT statements - same fix

Comment: @dbmitch That did fix the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements, thank you. Didn't even get far enough to realize they needed fixing lol. However, the issue with the `SELECT` statement has still not been resolved. Any idea how I can get the `SELECT` statement to run?

Comment: Update your code with what you have now - hard to work with a moving target

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recordset. In this case a recordset is better, since you only execute the SQL one time, if it returns a record, you "edit" and if not then you "add" with the SAME reocrdset. This approach is FAR less code, and the values you set into the reocrdset does not require messy quotes or delimiters etc.

eg:

```
scenaridID = 1             ' set this to any number
impvar1 = "Safety"         ' set this to any string
updateTo = "Financial"

strSQL = "select * from tImpact where [Impact Variable] = '" & impvar1 & "'" & _
        " AND scenaridID = " & scenaridID

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
With rst
  If .RecordCount = 0 Then
     ' add the reocrd
     .AddNew
  Else
     .Edit
  End If

  !scenaridID = scenarid
  ![Impact Variable] = impvar1
  ![Variable Impact] = 1
  .Update
End With
rst.Close
```

So you can use the same code for the update and the edit. It just a question if you add or edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OpenRecordset` and retrieve the ID for the record if it exists.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim aLookup(1 To 3) As String
    Dim aAction(1 To 3) As String
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim db As Database

    'Replace these two constants with where you get the information on your form
    Const sIMPVAR As String = "Financial"
    Const lSCENID As Long = 1

    'Build the SQL to find the ID if it exists
    aLookup(1) = "SELECT ID FROM tImpact"
    aLookup(2) = "WHERE ScenarioID = " & lSCENID
    aLookup(3) = "AND ImpactVariable = """ & sIMPVAR & """"

    'Run the sql to find the id
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(Join(aLookup, Space(1)))


    If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then 'it doesn't exist, so build the insert statement
        aAction(1) = "INSERT INTO tImpact"
        aAction(2) = "(ScenarioID, ImpactVariable, VariableImpact)"
        aAction(3) = "VALUES (" & lSCENID & ", '" & sIMPVAR & "', 1)"
    Else 'it does exist, so build the update statement
        aAction(1) = "UPDATE tImpact"
        aAction(2) = "SET VariableImpact = 1"
        aAction(3) = "WHERE ID = " & rs.Fields(0).Value
    End If

    'Run the action query
    db.Execute Join(aAction, Space(1))

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```